# SqlAlchemy: Join Two Tables With Not Equal Condition

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I two tables (`Loan_Contract` and `Loan_Amend`) that have same column `LoanID`. My purpose is that I want to get all data from table `Loan_Contract` only if they are not exist in table `Loan_Amend`.

So I tried my query as below:

```
db.session.query(
                Loan_Contract.ID,
                Loan_Contract.Currency,
                Loan_Contract.DisbursedAmount
            ).\
            join(Loan_Amend,Loan_Amend.LoanID != Loan_Contract.ID).\
            all()
```

And

```
db.session.query(
                Loan_Contract.ID,
                Loan_Contract.Currency,
                Loan_Contract.DisbursedAmount
            ).\
            join(Loan_Amend,Loan_Amend.LoanID == Loan_Contract.ID).\
            filter(Loan_Contract.ID != Loan_Amend.LoanID).\
            all()
```

However, either of query above returned all record from `Loan_Contract` even though `LoanID` exist in `Loan_Amend`.

What is correct way to archive result as expected above purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all `Loan_Contract` rows that don't have any `Loan_Amend` referring to it, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Loan_Contract LEFT JOIN Loan_Amend ON Loan_Contract.ID = Loan_Amend.LoanID
WHERE Loan_Amend.LoanID IS NULL;
```

Using SQLAlchemy:

```
session.query(Loan_Contract) \
       .outerjoin(Loan_Amend, Loan_Contract.ID == Loan_Amend.LoanID) \
       .filter(Loan_Amend.LoanID.is_(None))
```